Is there any way to make a Pygame code (often packed as an .exe) moddable?
I have a flight simulator game made with Pygame, and I was wondering if there is a way to make it moddable. Like for instance, a mod that adds a key to self-destruct your plane midair or a key that adds a smoke trail to your plane. (Neither of these features are in the game.)
My code follows this structure:
import pygame
# Rest of imports up here

# Initialization code

# Title Screen

running = True
while running:
    # Code here


How would I make a game like such moddable, including if the base game is packed as an EXE?
I was thinking sort of a list with all the mod pathnames, alongside a folder with the mods... but that would only work with a plain python script, not an EXE.
Tried to make a file alongside a folder, but that wouldn't work really well. Help!

the easiest way of making something moddable is reading features/settings from external files (like json files). You have a soldier with 40HP, 4 attack, 10 defense and 3 charisma? Put it in a json file and make your code read from it. Somebody can then mod your game by making another json file with different settings. The more settings you put into config files the more features from the game you will be able to mod.

You could create a folder in which all files are considered mods. For example the exe could create a folder "mods" in the same directory in which the exe is.
create directory:
from os import path, mkdir

if not path.exists(".\\mods_folder"):
    mkdir(".\\mods_folder")

exec code:
import os
for file in os.listdir(".\\mods_folder"):  #iterates over all files in mods_folder
    file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(".\\mods_folder", file)) #converts file name to path
    if not file.endswith(".py"): #checks if file is a python script
        continue
    with open(file, "r") as f: #opens the file
        exec(f.read())  #reads the file and executes the python code inside

Note: Simple reading a file and executing its content is not safe. You should not do this in a program that you intend to publish, but it is great if you just want to play around in a fun project.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Good point, but how exactly do I make it make folders? Or make it execute the code in said folder?
